# Proving the closed unit sphere of the sup-norm is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{f\in V\ |\ \lVert{f}\rVert\leq 1\}$, with $\lVert{f}\rVert=\sup\{|f(x)|\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. For $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ the set of bounded functions.

I want to prove that A is closed.

I started with assuming that $f\in V$ is a limitpoint of A. I know I need to get $\lVert f\rVert \leq 1$, but I don't know how I can get this.
Because $f$ is a limitpoint of $A$, we know that $\forall\delta >0\ B(f,\delta)\cap A\neq\emptyset$. So let $g\in V$ be an element of this intersection. Then $\lVert f-g \rVert \leq 1$ and $\lVert g\rVert\leq 1$. But from here I don't know how to get any further.

Answer (score 2):

**Let's abstract a bit the question...**

We are asked to prove that a closed ball $A$ with radius equal to $1$ in a normed vector space is closed. This is very generic.

A simple proof is to consider the complement $V \setminus A$ and to prove that it is open. This is simple as for $f \in V \setminus A$, we have $\Vert f \Vert = r > 1$. The open ball centered on $f$ with radius $\frac{r-1}{2}$ is included in $V \setminus A$. This ends the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f \in V$ be a limit point of $A$. Then there is a sequence $(f_n)$ in $A$ such that $||f_n-f|| \to 0$ as $(n \to \infty)$.

Then we have that $||f_n|| \to ||f||$ as $(n \to \infty)$.

Can you proceed to show that $||f|| \le 1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f_n \to f$ with $\Vert f_n \Vert \leq 1$, then also $\Vert f_n \Vert \to \Vert f \Vert$ by the reverse triangle inequality, and limits preserve inequalities.